# iOS - not getting push notification from APN - how to debug?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to add push notifications ability to my app. I followed all the steps in order to do so. I can see that my app is registering the device token in my server, and I see that my server sends the notification.
I'm using a development key, and a development provisioning profile. Is the a way do debug this? I have no idea what the problem is, since I don't have any errors in my app.

I am sure that the code on my server works, because I had an older version of the app that worked with the server code. I think it's a configuration problem on the Xcode project, but I can't find the problem.

Comment: You  should  try Parse.com to send and verify you  certificate are valid or not. than if it works  than only you should check the code at server side for any bugs.

Comment: I'm sure it's not the server. It's something in the Xcode configuration. I just can't figure out what it is.

Comment: Please refer this which might help step by step process.. http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Comment: That's exactly what I did. Are you sure it works for Xcode 6, and iPhone with iOS 7.2?

Comment: no major change i thinks on coding of pushnotification. so it should work.

Comment: Are you  able t o get  device token properly.

Comment: Yes. I can see it in my logs.

Comment: I just finished following this tutorial again step-by-step, and it still doesn't work. Can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: than may be certificate issue. Please check that.  and confirm  if certificate being used is right or not using parse pushnotification service

Comment: In the end it was a certificates problem. It works now. Thanks!

Comment: How did you determine it was a certs problem? I suspect I have the same problem.

Comment: Using same certificate in parse.com sample app of pushnotification @MauryMarkowitz